# combine multiple array together from the same array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects

```
const line_items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        components: [
            { name: "nadia" },
            { name: "tim" },
            { name: "mark" },
            { name: "alex" }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 1,
        components: [ 
            { name: "ramsey" } 
        ]
    }
];
```

I want to combine all components into one array. the result would be

```
[
    { name: "nadia" },
    { name: "tim" },
    { name: "mark" },
    { name: "alex" },
    { name: "ramsey" }
]
```

### my attempt

```js
function pretty(obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) }

const line_items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        components: [
            { name: "nadia" },
            { name: "tim" },
            { name: "mark" },
            { name: "alex" }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 1,
        components: [ 
            { name: "ramsey" } 
        ]
    }
];

const all_components = line_items;

console.log(pretty(all_components));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.flatMap()` (not supported by IE/Edge):

```js
const line_items = [{"id":1,"components":[{"name":"nadia"},{"name":"tim"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"alex"}]},{"id":1,"components":[{"name":"ramsey"}]}];

const all_components = line_items.flatMap(o => o.components);

console.log(pretty(all_components));

function pretty(obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) }
```

And if flatMap is not supported you can use `Array.map()` with spread and `Array.concat()`:

```js
const line_items = [{"id":1,"components":[{"name":"nadia"},{"name":"tim"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"alex"}]},{"id":1,"components":[{"name":"ramsey"}]}];

const all_components = [].concat(...line_items.map(o => o.components));

console.log(pretty(all_components));

function pretty(obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and pass components to [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) using Rest Parameters.

```js
const line_items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        components: [
            { name: "nadia" },
            { name: "tim" },
            { name: "mark" },
            { name: "alex" }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 1,
        components: [ 
            { name: "ramsey" } 
        ]
    }
];

let allcomps = line_items.reduce((ac,a) => ac.concat(...a.components),[])
console.log(allcomps)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reduce the items.

```js
const
    line_items = [{ id: 1, components: [{ name: "nadia" }, { name: "tim" }, { name: "mark" }, { name: "alex" }] }, { id: 1, components: [{ name: "ramsey" }] }],
    result = line_items.reduce((r, { components }) => [...r, ...components], []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)  for this.

```
const line_items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        components: [
            { name: "nadia" },
            { name: "tim" },
            { name: "mark" },
            { name: "alex" }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 1,
        components: [ 
            { name: "ramsey" } 
        ]
    }
];

var result = line_items.flatMap((i)=>{ return i['components'];});

console.log(result);
```